# Remove characters after forward slash in file

Tags: python, file, csv

I have a .csv file with this content:

HEAD / HTTP/1.1

POST /app/something1/ HTTP/1.1

GET /app/something2/ HTTP/1.1

GET /app/something3/ HTTP/1.1

and can't find a way to remove everything after the first fw slash.

I've tried some regex but without such a knowledge it looks more difficult than going with python.

This is basic code that I've tried:

```
with open('log1.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        f[:f.index("/")]
```

The expected result is this:

Head

POST

GET

GET

Can you please assist me on the right code portion?

Comment: There's a bunch of wrong things here. First, you shouldn't open with the 'w' parameter if you want to read something. Put 'r' instead or better, don't put nothing. Second, you're not even trying to read the file. Do `for line in f.readlines()` to start the cycle. Third, you're not even trying to print something. Wrap the last row with the `print()` function.

Comment: TY guys, I've fixed this with your recommendations but still unable to get the output. Meaning like when executing it it finishes ok, even if I print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to read each line in, and `split()` on `'\'` and index the first item:

```
# Open the file in read more
# mode='r' by default if you don't specify
with open('log1.csv') as f:

    # Read each line from the iterator
    for line in f:

        # Strip newlines
        line = line.strip()

        # Only process non-empty lines
        if line:

            # Split the line and take the first item
            print(line.split('/')[0])
```

Output:

```
HEAD 
POST 
GET
GET
```